# error in insert sql statement

Tags: php, sql-server, mysqli

this is sign up form pls help me to solve this error

ERROR: Could not able to execute  sql insert statement

```
INSERT INTO customer(customer_id,customer_name,customer_email,customer_password) VALUES (null,'','','').Column 'customer_id' cannot be null

//check connection
if($link===false){
die("ERROR: could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

//Escape user inputs for security
$customer_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $REQUEST['customerid']);
$customer_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $REQUEST['Name']);
$customer_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $REQUEST['Email']);
$customer_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $REQUEST['Password']);

//attempt insert query execution
$sql="INSERT INTO customer(customer_id,customer_name,customer_email,customer_password) VALUES (null,'$customer_name','$customer_email','$customer_password')";

if(mysqli_query($link,$sql)){
echo "records added successfully.";
} else{
echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql.".mysqli_error($link);
}

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: So what do you want from us? The error is very clear; you are trying to insert null in an attribute that doesn't accept null

Comment: Probably `customer_id` is `IDENTITY`, so you just need to exclude it from `INSERT` statement

Comment: Read my answer. I hope you will solve your error.

Comment: if i do that i get like this feel lie cryERROR: Could not able to execute INSERT INTO customer(customer_name,customer_email,customer_password) VALUES (null'','','').You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''','','')' at line 1

Answer (score 2):

It says in your error message that the column `customer_id`can not be null.
Looking at your query `VALUES (null,'$customer_name','$customer_email','$customer_password')";` the values start after the parenthesis. So your first column is `customer_id` and the first value is `null`.

The error message tells you that your table is not setup to allow for `customer_id` to be `null`. So you either have to change to database table structure or your query. As it is about an ID I suggest you change your query.

If `customer_id` is an auto incremented field you should simply not set it (remove it from your query)

**Edit:**

It is not usual to have an identifier set to varchar. Seeing something like `customer_id` lets most people assume that they are dealing with an integer. The easiest approach would be to make that table column an integer with auto increment in your database (in most cases such a field would also be primary key).
Seeing that your table requires the field `customer_id` it can not be left out from your query and you would have to generate / create an adequate identifier for your customer. A workaround for your current table structure:

```
$sql="
INSERT INTO 
    customer
    (customer_id,customer_name,customer_email,customer_p‌​‌​assword) 
VALUES (
(select count(customer_id) from customer)+1,'$customer_name','$customer_email','$customer_pa‌​ssword‌​')";
```

**Edit 2:**
Some additional information on database column data types: [mysql char vs. varchar](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html) and [mysql integer](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html)

if you later on have a more complex database and query multiple tables at once to gather your data you will have to rely on your indices and realtions (foreign keys) to get the results fast. IE: having a join on your `customer_id` is rather slow. setting it to char lets it operate faster due to varchar having a variable length. I have not yet tested the performance regarding `char` and `integer`

Comment: im not understand can u give some example plc plc plc

Comment: your current query `$sql="INSERT INTO customer(customer_id,customer_name,customer_email,customer_password) VALUES (null,'$customer_name','$customer_email','$customer_password')";` a query with customer_id removed `$sql="INSERT INTO customer(customer_name,customer_email,customer_password) VALUES ('$customer_name','$customer_email','$customer_password')";`

Comment: but after remove the query it like this ERROR: Could not able to execute INSERT INTO customer(customer_name,customer_email,customer_password) VALUES ('','','').Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY

Comment: I'm starting to question your table structure. can you tell us how you created the table? (columns, indices, is any column set to auto increment)

Comment: no im not set anything in auto increment i do the table in phpmyadmin                            ALTER TABLE  `customer` CHANGE  `customer_id`  `customer_id` VARCHAR( 50 ) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL ,
CHANGE  `customer_name`  `customer_name` VARCHAR( 50 ) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL ,
CHANGE  `customer_email`  `customer_email` VARCHAR( 50 ) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL ,
CHANGE  `customer_password`  `customer_password` VARCHAR( 50 ) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL

Comment: ok... using varchar for an id? normally I'd expect it to be integer or biginteger. to fix your query: `$sql="INSERT INTO customer(customer_id,customer_name,customer_email,customer_p‌​assword) VALUES ((select count(customer_id) from customer)+1,'$customer_name','$customer_email','$customer_password‌​')";` this should work (but is very bad style.)

Comment: So the problem is that you created a column that can not be null and try to insert a value of `null`for that column. if you use phpmyadmin to change customer_id to integer, make it primary and set it to auto_increment you can remove `customer_id` from your query. I'll update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: but this style my professor teach me ok i try ur style first i go and change the id as int and i try to change the query tq

Comment: the bad style I'm talking about is to use a workaround like I provided to fill your `customer_id`

Comment: tq so much for ur help

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `customer_id` instead of `null` in the query, e.g.:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO customer(customer_id,customer_name,customer_email,customer_password) 
VALUES ('$customer_id','$customer_name','$customer_email','$customer_password')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove customer_id column like below,

```
$sql="INSERT INTO customer(customer_name,customer_email,customer_password) 
VALUES ('$customer_name','$customer_email','$customer_password')";
```

If you set customer_id as auto increment in database there no need to include it in query

Answer (score 0):

If your `customer_id` is an `autoincrement id` of your `customer` table then, no need to put it inside your **INSERT** statement.

Simply run without customer_id

```
$sql="INSERT INTO customer(customer_name,customer_email,customer_password) 
VALUES ('$customer_name','$customer_email','$customer_password')";
```

Ok. Let me explain you somethings.

> Case 1 :

If your **customer_id** is an integer type and `you have not put anything` in **default** value then it will ***not allow*** you to insert a **null** into that field. For that, you need to set **default** value as `NULL`.

> Case 2

If your `customer_id` is an `autoincrement id` of `customer` table then you can't set null into it during a SQL statement.